# Java 8 - How to use predicate that has a function with parameter?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, predicate

I have the following code:

```
public boolean isImageSrcExists(String imageSrc) {
    int resultsNum = 0;
    List<WebElement> blogImagesList = driver.findElements(blogImageLocator);

    for (WebElement thisImage : blogImagesList) {
        if (thisImage.getAttribute("style").contains(imageSrc)) {
            resultsNum++;
        }
    }

    if (resultsNum == 2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What is the proper way of converting it to use Java 8 `Stream`s?

When I'm trying to use `map()`, I get an error since `getAttribute` isn't a `Function`.

```
int a = (int) blogImagesList.stream()
                            .map(WebElement::getAttribute("style"))
                            .filter(s -> s.contains(imageSrc))
                            .count();
```

Comment: we could make some "curry" thingy, but it's probably not worth it - `curry(::getAttribute, "style")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot do exactly what you want - explicit parameters are not allowed in method references.

But you could...

...create a method that returns a boolean and harcoded the call to `getAttribute("style")`:

```
public boolean getAttribute(final T t) {
    return t.getAttribute("style");
}
```

This would allow you to use the method ref:

```
int a = (int) blogImagesList.stream()
              .map(this::getAttribute)
              .filter(s -> s.contains(imageSrc))
              .count();
```

...or you could define a variable to hold the function:

```
final Function<T, R> mapper = t -> t.getAttribute("style");
```

This would allow you to simply pass the variable

```
int a = (int) blogImagesList.stream()
              .map(mapper)
              .filter(s -> s.contains(imageSrc))
              .count();
```

...or you could curry and combine the above two approaches (this is certainly horribly overkill)

```
public Function<T,R> toAttributeExtractor(String attrName) {
    return t -> t.getAttribute(attrName);
}
```

Then you would need to call `toAttributeExtractor` to get a `Function` and pass that into the `map`:

```
final Function<T, R> mapper = toAttributeExtractor("style");
int a = (int) blogImagesList.stream()
              .map(mapper)
              .filter(s -> s.contains(imageSrc))
              .count();
```

Although, realistically, simply using a lambda would be easier (as you do on the next line):

```
int a = (int) blogImagesList.stream()
              .map(t -> t.getAttribute("style"))
              .filter(s -> s.contains(imageSrc))
              .count();
```

Comment: Why do you have all these awkward solutions in the middle instead of going directly to the solution at the end?

Comment: @LouisWasserman because the OP wanted a workaround - I wanted to illustrate that the simple  solution the OP was already using is the best one.

Answer (score 7):

You can't pass a parameter to a method reference. You can use a lambda expression instead :

```
int a = (int) blogImagesList.stream()
                            .map(w -> w.getAttribute("style"))
                            .filter(s -> s.contains(imageSrc))
                            .count();
```

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting the code so you could read it without scrolling.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks :)