# Is it possible to use method reference in the below code snippet

Tags: java, selenium, java-8

I am new to java 8 and I am learning method reference. I was coding and I used lambda expression in the below case. But the sonar lint says that the below lines can be further reduces by using method reference. Now I am confused about it's implemenetation as there is

1. Typecasting
2. I read that in method refernce should be used when we are just passing what is coming.
   For example `o -> System.out.println(o)` could be written as `System.out::println`
   Can method reference be implemented in the below case

   ```
   ExpectedCondition<Boolean> cc = (x) -> {
           JavascriptExecutor j = (JavascriptExecutor) x;
           return (Boolean) j.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals(completeString);
       };
   ```

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32332582/2071828) about using method references for calls with parameters.

Comment: Should it be `.equals(x)` instead of `.equals(completeString)`?

Comment: @AndreasLundgren It is comepleteString that is a separate string

Comment: @BoristheSpider x is WebDriver's reference and j = (JavascriptExecutor) x;

Comment: @BeginnersSake of course, sorry - being stupid. Completely missed the cast there... You can use a chain of `Function.compose` to do the various operations. I don't see that as an improvement however. As a matter of coding style, I require multiline lambdas moved into a well named method where appropriate; but other than that I would leave this code be.

Comment: It can be reduced to expression form: `ExpectedCondition<Boolean> cc = (x) -> ((JavascriptExecutor)x).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString() .equals(completeString);` but not to a method reference (unless you create a dedicated method containing that code, but that’s not a simplification, it’s exactly what a lambda expression does for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Boolean fun(WebDriver d)
    {
        JavascriptExecutor j = (JavascriptExecutor) d;
        return (Boolean) j.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("");
    }
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> cd = this::fun;
```